# Set different memory engine with mysqldump

Tags: unix, mysql

I want to make a copy of my mysql database using mysqldump.

I use this unix command

```
mysqldump db1 | mysql db2
```

However db1 are all tables with engine=myisam. I want db2 to have all tables with engine=memory.

Does anybody know a way to do this in one command? I don't want to have to invoke a php/python etc. script for changing all tables in a for-loop.

Thanks

Comment: you could pipe through `sed` and replace `MyISAM` with `memory`, or whatever the exact strings are. But if your db data naturally includes the word `myisam`, you'd be changing the data, not just the table structure. Better option would be to dump to a temporary file, edit that file and do a proper change of all the structures, then do the import.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I want to have it in a unix command so I wouldn't have to use script or plugins. Because the original database is on a different server then the destination database.

Comment: so use `sed`, with the awareness that you could potentially corrupt your db's data if you search/replace the wrong thing.

Comment: To avoid the risk of mistakenly altering the data, proceed in two steps: `mysqldump --no-data`, then `mysqldump --no-create-table`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Marc B I found this solution.

```
mysqldump db1 > dump.sql && sed -i 's/ENGINE=MyISAM/ENGINE=MEMORY/g' dump.sql && mysql db2 < dump.sql && rm -rf dump.sql
```

By using the entire string 'ENGINE=MyISAM' I think this will never create a problem. Else you can use the 2 step option from RandomSeed (with a minor adjustment: --no-create-table should be --no-create-info):

```
mysqldump --no-data db1 > dump.sql && sed -i 's/ENGINE=MyISAM/ENGINE=MEMORY/g' dump.sql && mysql db2 < dump.sql && mysqldump --no-create-info db1 | mysql db2 && rm -rf dump.sql
```

This two step method is safer if you have a possibility of having 'ENGINE=MyISAM' somewhere in your data. However your data (in db2) is not accessible for the time the command is executed so this can cause problems for large databases.

Thank you for your input.